# How to resolve Conflict: 'Deleted on Source, Modified on Target ' when using jest snapshottesting?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bitbucket, jestjs, bamboo

I am using bitbucket and having this error when I want to merge from develop to master:

This file is in a conflicted state. You will need to resolve the conflict manually before you can merge this pull request.

I can change the the file that causes the conflict to be the exact same as the master version but then the snapshot test will fail. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Update your snapshots if you know the change is legit and push the change.